# How can I use htaccess to get query and redirect to another url (adding the query)?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site and we send a monthly newsletter.
The newsletter subscribe and unsubscribe functions are managed on another domain.

But, to keep the newsletter footer "pretty", I would prefer that the unsubscribe link indicates the main domain.

SO:
Following this link from the newsletters footer:

```
http://maindomain.com/?email=some@email.com
```

BUT REALLY NEED:

```
http://maindomain.com/?noemail=some@email.com
```

Would redirect user to:

```
http://listdomain.com/members/?p=blacklist&email=some@email.com
```

Is this possible?

I have been struggling with trying to figure out how:

```
RewriteRule ^(I HAVE NO IDEA*)$ /?email=$1&rewrite [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} email=(I HAVE NO IDEA*)$
GO TO THE OTHER URL SOMEHOW
```

and so on BUT I AM CLUELESS and been reading for an entire day.

Thanks so much for teaching this old dog...

I may be getting closer but, need help:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^email=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc$ http://listdomain.com/members/?p=blacklist&email=%1? [R=301,L]
```

I tried this and it worked but, I am afraid it may not be the "best" method.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((?<!email=).*@.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://listdomain.com/members/?p=blacklist&%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Above works with email query but, need to rewrite "noemail" in the original query to "email".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You merely need to add the `[QSA]` flag (query string append) to add the existing querystring onto the redirect. IT should be appended after any parameters you added (`p=blacklist`)

```
RewriteRule ^abc$ http://listdomain.com/members/?p=blacklist [R=301,L,QSA]
```

From the [Apache mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. **To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.**

#### Update:

If this must only happen when email= is present:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} email=(.+)
RewriteRule ^abc$ http://listdomain.com/members/?p=blacklist [R=301,L,QSA]
```

### Update 2:

If I understand all of this now, you want to capture `noemail` and pass that to the `email=` in `listdomain.com`.
To rewrite `email` to `noemail`, you *do* need a `RewriteCond` that captures the parameter.

```
# capture email into %1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST] ^maindomain.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} noemail=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ http://listdomain.com/members/?p=blacklist&email=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you but, that had no effect. I used the condition from the second example from above and then your example. I am not just that advanced to figure this out. I tried another way and it works but, may be UN-desireable? I am adding that it above.

Comment: @Jim_Bo You should not need any `RewriteCond`.  The single rule should work. In any case, if you do _only_ want this to happen if the email param is there, I'll add a simpler RewriteCond above.

Comment: Thank you but, that still just stays on the same page no redirect like my last example above that works. ALSO how would I turn noemail into email in the query. So sorry I did not specify more clearly.

Comment: can you help me get the last part fixed in my last example where "noemail" needs to be renamed to email? I would like to check your answer and implement asap. Thanks!

Comment: @Jim_Bo I think I get it now? see above.

Comment: KUDOS! THANK YOU, and I think I may actually understand!